# Say $[G:H]=t$ and $G$ acts on the cosets of $H$ in $G$ by either conjugation or left multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Say $[G:H]=t$ and $G$ acts on the cosets of $H$ in $G$ by either conjugation or left multiplication. This induces a homomorphism:

$\alpha: G \rightarrow S_t$

Now, my question is, does is it always true that $ker(\alpha) \leq H$? I have made sense of why this is true if the action is left multiplication, but is it also true if the action is by conjugation??

If somebody could shed some insight on the characterizing differences between an action of cosets by conjugation vs left (or right) multiplication, that would be awesome!

Comment: If $xH$ is a left coset, then in general $gxHg^{-1}$ is not a left coset; and if $xH=yH$, this does not imply that $gxg^{-1}H = gyg^{-1}H$. So how do you act by conjugation?

Comment: (For example, if $G=S_3$, $H=\{1,(12)\}$, then $(123)H = (13)H$, but conjugating by $(13)$ would give $(132)H$ for one and $(13)H$ for the other)

Comment: Okay, so you can only act by conjugation on certain subgroups, like sylow-p subgroups.

Comment: You can act by conjugation on subgroups; but not on **cosets of a subgroup**.  Your comment is as if, after being told you cannot eat styrofoam peanuts, you say “Oh, I guess you can only eat certain kind of nuts, like walnuts.”

Comment: Ahaaa my boy's got jokes! edit: ENLIGHTENING JOKES!! thanks dawg your the man!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you act on cosets by conjugation ? $gHg^{-1}$ is not, in general, a coset of $H$. For instance if $gHg^{-1} \neq H$ then it can't be a coset because it's a subgroup, and the only coset that is also a subgroup is $H$ itself.

Of course, acting on them by multiplication, you say that if $g\in \ker(\alpha)$ then $g\cdot H = gH = H$, so that $g\in H$, so $\ker(\alpha)\leq H$